# Declaring non-serializable object in a non-atomic orchestration

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013, biztalk-orchestrations

I have an orchestration with transaction type set to None.
Within the orchestration I invoke a C# helper class which is referenced in the orchestration project.
On building I get the error

> a non-serializable object type can only be declared within an atomic scope or service.

To get round this I tried to change the transaction type of the orchestration to atomic, but that won't work as from within it I also have to call another orchestration, which gives the error

> an atomic scope may not contain or call a service or scope that contains both the send and the corresponding receive of a requestresponse operation on a 'uses' port or servicelink

Can anyone point me in the right direction here?

Comment: What prevents you from using a long-running transaction in your orchestration? What is the transaction level of the called orchestration?

Comment: The transaction level is currently 'None', and this gives the 1st error in my post.  If set to long-running I get the same error.

Comment: problem solved I think, (though still to test properly).  Have done the call-orchestration near the start of the main orchestration, then have everything else inside an atomic scope - we'll see how that goes

Comment: Would you care to respond this in an answer yourself please? This way, the question is also marked as solved.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. Have done the call-orchestration near the start of the main orchestration, then have everything else inside an atomic scope.
@Pieter - thanks once again for looking at another of my Biztalk questions